# Trigger, o editar archivo sin permiso (no formulario) Google script

Tags: trigger, google-apps-script, permisos

He creado un panel mediante doGet (panel HTML), vinculado a una hoja de cálculo. La misma la utilizaran supervisores de la empresa en donde trabajo. Depende de que supervisor abra la página, le aparecerán en una lista desplegable solo los empleados de sus sector. (getEffectiveUser).
Al seleccionar un empleado de la lista desplegable, extrae del archivo algunos datos correspondiente al empleado

El inconveniente que tengo es que debo darle permiso a los supervisores para que editen el archivo (por más que lo hagan desde el panel HTML), y la idea es que esas personas no puedan ver el archivo. El archivo se puede compartir a la organización sin que las personas se den cuenta, pero cuando cuando cargan datos mediante el panel html, el archivo les aparece en el Drive en la parte de "Recientes". 
Un formulario no me es útil ya que no extrae datos de una hoja de cálculos dinámicamente.

Probé con agregar un archivo de modo "interfase", pero el cambio se debe hacer manual para ejecutar un activador, y por tiempo, el mínimo es de 1 minuto y es demasiado, ya que debe ser automática la devolución de la carga de la hoja de cálculo al panel html.

Comment: Igual te digo una tontería muy gorda (hace tiempo hice algo parecido, pero igual me equivoco). Has probado a publicar el proyecto como una aplicación web que la ejecución se haga desde tu usuario? Así solo tu tendrías permisos sobre ese fichero y nadie se enteraría ni tan siquiera de su existencia. Para que los usuarios accedan a la web podrías hacerlo o bien directamente dándoles la url de la aplicación web o bien encastando la aplicación dentro de un google site sencillo. (aquí tienes un [tutorial](http://googleappscriptsweb.blogspot.com.es/2015/03/como-crear-una-web-dinamica-con-google.html

Comment: Algo importante que te faltó mencionar es si estás usando cuentas de consumidor (gratuitas) o si estas usando cuentas de G Suite.